# How to implement a flexible progress bar with inverted text color with pure css?

Tags: html, css

I'm implementing a **flexible** progress bar with inverted text color using **pure css**.

Please refer to the following pens for what I mean.

[CSS progress bar with inverted colors](http://codepen.io/lzl124631x/pen/YWQLrE)

[CSS Progress bars](http://codepen.io/lzl124631x/pen/oLwEwq)

[image]

The problem is that the progress bars in these two implementations are of **fixed width** (with fixed width, it's possible to set the length/position of `.progress-text`), but I want progress bar to **be of width `100%` or some other relative length**. It's hard to adapt above pens into what I need without JS.

My failed experiment goes [here](http://codepen.io/lzl124631x/pen/oLwyjo). Can you adjust the implementation to make the `.progress` support relative width like `50%`?

Here is the snippet. Thanks @TheThirdMan.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.progress {
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #07A4DD;
  border-radius: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.progress .progress-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
.progress .progress-bar {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 54%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: animate 4s;
          animation: animate 4s;
}
.progress .progress-bar .progress-text {
  color: #07A4DD;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Flexible CSS progress bar with inverted colors</h1>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-text">Progress</div>
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-text">Progress</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Thanks for @AndrewBone's answer. But I have some reason not to use `vw` in this problem:

1. We tried `vw` before for other problems but some android device doesn't support it, so we dropped it.
2. There are some, if not many, cases that the parent of `.progress` is not proportioned to the viewport's width.

---

Here is my experiment. My idea is resembling to [CSS Progress bars](http://codepen.io/lzl124631x/pen/oLwEwq).

The idea is that:

- Both `.progress-text` are absolute positioned and as wide as `.progress`.
- The first `.progress-text` is the white one, which resides in the `.progress` as a background.
- The second `.progress-text` is the blue text, which is clipped by `.progress-bar`.

These lead to:

- `.progress-bar` has to be relative positioned to get `.progress-text` clipped.
- `.progress-text` cannot get the width of `.progress` as it's (absolutely) positioned to `.progress-bar` but not `.progress`.

So:

- if `.progress` is of fixed width (e.g.`$bar-width: 500px`), I can center the `.progres-text` by setting its width the same as `.progress`'s width.
- if `.progress` is of relative width (e.g. `$bar-width: 50%`), what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Why do you need the progress bar to have width of 100%? I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What is it that you're updating or changing that you want to show the progress of? Without JavaScript this seems theoretically possible, the style of the progress bar could be influenced by the number of previous siblings for example, but without JavaScript where are those siblings coming from?

Comment: @Slayther I want the progress bar to fill its parent (whose width is not predetermined), rather than be of fixed width. This makes the progress bar more adaptive to different viewport width

Comment: I believe the only thing they want is to have the width CSS-based, not JS-generated, so that it adjusts to responsive layouts better. But as a hint to the questioner, the reason why this probably got downvoted (not by me) is that you should include code in your question, not just as a link; but more importantly, that you need to show your work before asking a question.

Comment: @TheThirdMan I did my work before, which is inside of the pen... (T_T). I didn't put the code here because it's a bit long. Trust me. I did my experiment but failed.

Comment: @DavidThomas Updating the progress must involve JS. But for the layout part, I wonder if it's possible to let the `.progress-text` stay centered using pure CSS. I, of course, could keep them centered using JS, but I've seen some fancy implementations beyond my imagination making some complex gadgets with pure CSS. I tried but failed in this case so I'm here to see if someone could come up with a genius idea.

Comment: In which case you need to fully and clearly explain your own idea and expected outcome, and how that outcome should occur (in response to what actions or events). You also need to show your "*[MCVE]*" code so that we can see what you were trying to do, and where you went wrong. That way you learn something from your mistakes, and we may have a better understanding of what you were attempting.

Comment: @TheThirdMan It's also hard to ask a concrete technical question (if you insist, could be "how to let an element know it's grandparent's width in css) as for my problem, because I'm afraid that my html design might lead to a dead end. So I asked a open question so that others might not be confined to my html design and come up with another one.

Comment: @DavidThomas I knew that. This is not my first SO question... But this time my problem is not a simple one. My minimal complete and verifiable example lives in the pen.

Comment: If you don't need percentages and relative units like `50vw` (50% of viewport) are ok, it's as easy as it gets: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzjBKN (alter the browser window width to see the dynamic width).

Comment: @Paul I've thought of that. But 1. we tried `vw` before but some android device doesn't support it. 2. There are cases that the parent of `.progress` might not be proportioned with the viewport.

Comment: @Moon: I edited your post with a minimal and verifyable example (waiting for verification) that's easy to pick up by users and edit to help you give you your answer. Converting the SASS code into normal CSS and cleaning the code up isn't all that much work, but it's work you should have done, not someone else for you.

Comment: @TheThirdMan Thanks for your help. But the edit is rejected... I pasted the most important parts into the post and added my explanation. Hope you feel better this time.

Comment: @Moon: Please don't think I'm trying to pick a fight - I'm only trying to explain my guesses as why this post has been originally downvoted, and following from that, why people might hesitate answering. Please look into snippets, which is a native way this site provides in order to display html+css+js (something my edit had, for that matter), which won't vanish from the internet at an undetermined point in time and which is easily copied into answers. What you posted is furthermore not CSS, but SCSS code.

Comment: @TheThirdMan Of course I felt your kindness. I'm glad that you gave me suggestions and helped editing. I'm just frustrated by the down-votes and rushing to elaborate my question in order to make them satisfied. You are way better than those who down-voted without any comment. I'll give snippet a try. It's SCSS, my fault :P Thanks again :D

Comment: @TheThirdMan By the way your word "won't vanish from the internet at an undetermined point in time and which is easily copied into answers" really makes me realized the importance of snippet. Indeed a link to codepen is not as longlasting as a snippet here. I'll use snippet as much as I can in the future.

Comment: I've been toying around with this a lot (pretty much since you asked the question), using a lot of hacks I've come accross over the years, and there's no apparent way this seems to be possible. It would be easy with black font over both bars instead of that negative effect, or with left-aligned text, or with the help of javascript on load... but it seems impossible to get `overflow:hidden` to work with `position:absolute`, which you both need to solve this problem the exact way you want it. Maybe I'll think of something during the day, but for now, my guess is that this isn't possible...

Comment: @TheThirdMan. I really appreciate your help. I've thought of left/right-aligned text, I could make it, but it's not my ideal effect (centered text on a flexible progress bar is beautiful, isn't it? :D ). With JS this problem would be a piece of cake. You're right in that `overflow:hidden` and `position: absolute` are the culprit of this problem. It seems to be a simple center-positioning problem involving clipping but I just cannot make it work using css. Recently I've seen some fancy implementation using ONLY css  which I thought IMPOSSIBLE without JS before. So here I am.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's an idea, I may be wrong here so feel free to correct me. `vw` ([REF](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)) is a fancy CSS3 thing that means viewport width, in the example below is used 75vw which means 75% of the viewport width. It works and the size is responsive as you change the page.

On top of that, I've added a CSS variable just so that I only needed to type it once during testing. CSS variables are new and shiny but aren't in all browsers yet ([REF](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables))

```css
:root {
  --progress-width: 75vw;
}
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.progress {
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  width: var(--progress-width, 500px);
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #07A4DD;
  border-radius: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.progress .progress-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: var(--progress-width, 500px);
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
.progress .progress-bar {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 54%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: animate 4s;
  animation: animate 4s;
}
.progress .progress-bar .progress-text {
  color: #07A4DD;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-text">Progress</div>
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-text">Progress</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as what I've replied to @Paul, I have reason not to use `vw`. 1. we tried vw before but some android device doesn't support it. 2. There are cases that the parent of .progress might not be proportioned with the viewport.